# Dictionary Retrieve Value and remember Key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a dictionary to store values of temperatures, with the key being the day of the temperature and the value being the temperature.

```
day = {day: temperature, 1: 32, 2: 29, 3: 25, 4: 34}
```

I want to get the max temperature, so I use max:

```
max(day.values)
```

This gives me the highest temperature. However, I also need to know which day that temperature was on. How do I get what key this value is from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another shorter alternative:

```
max(temp, key=temp.get)
=> 4
```

Now we now that the highest day was `4`, and it's easy to retrieve the temperature:

```
temp[4]
=> 34
```

Comment: Yeah, if you only want the day, this works.  You can even shorten to `max(temp, key=temp.__getitem__)` if you really want to.

Comment: Short solutions are always the best :) this solution also easily allows retrieval of either value, whereas other answers put them both in the same line, e.g. `(3, 21)`

Answer (score 4):

`max` accepts a `key` function.  you can use that to look at the *items* in the dictionary and compare the items by value:

```
max(day.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

This will return the item (key-value pair) from the dictionary with the greatest value.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the key of the max function. The python [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) builtin function accepts an optional key argument which accepts a ordering function.

```
>>> day= {1: 32, 2: 29, 3: 25, 4: 34}
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(day.items(), key = itemgetter(1))
(4, 34)
```

This returns a pair of day and temperature. You can index the pair to retrieve the specific details.